# What is the difference between the Seeduino Electronic Brick shield vs the chassis?

Tags: arduino

As far as i can tell they are both Arduino shields. Is that correct?

- The [electronic brick shield](http://www.seeedstudio.com/depot/electronic-brick-shield-v4-p-458.html?cPath=132_134)
- The [electronic brick chassis](http://www.seeedstudio.com/depot/electronic-brick-chassis-v11-p-460.html?cPath=132_134)

If they are indeed both shields, what's the difference between them and why would someone buy one over the other? Their wiki is incomplete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Shield is intended only for Arduino boards, whereas the Brick Chassis can be used with any system with compatible connectors. It could be used with an Arduino, of course, with suitable connectors and cables. It isn't a Shield, it looks as though they put it in the wrong category. You could email them to make sure.